# Can I make sure that a "cordoned" node is the one deleted when I downsize the cluster in Azure AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I need to downsize a cluster from 3 to 2 nodes.
I have critical pods running on some nodes (0 and 1). As I found that the last node (2) in the cluster is the one that has the non critical pods, I have "cordoned" it so it won't get any new ones.
I wonder is if I can make sure that that last node (2) is the one that will be removed when I go to Azure portal and downsize my cluster to 2 nodes (it is the last node and it is cordoned).

I have read that if I manually delete the node, the system will still consider there are 3 nodes running so it's important to use the cluster management to downsize it.

Comment: "As I found that the last node (2) in the cluster is the one that has the non critical nodes, " Did you mean "non critical pods"?

Comment: Oooops. Correct @OhHiMark. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control which node will be removed when scaling down the AKS cluster.

However, there are some workarounds for that:

1. Delete the cordoned node manually via portal and than launch upgrade. It would try to add the node but with no success because the subnet has no space left.
2. Another option is to:

   - Set up cluster autoscaler with two nodes
   - Scale up the number of nodes in the UI
   - Drain the node you want to delete and wait for autoscaler do it's job

Here are some sources and useful info:

- [Scale the node count in an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/scale-cluster)
- [Support selection of nodes to remove when scaling down](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/914020-azure-kubernetes-service-aks/suggestions/35702938-support-selection-of-nodes-to-remove-when-scaling)
- [`az aks scale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-scale)

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks, it definitely helps. What do you mean by "launch upgrade" exactly? About option 2): I have 3 nodes, last one already cordoned. I would set autoscaler to only 2 nodes and then scale it up to 3 in the UI. How would that make autoscaler delete the node 3? Thanks for any clarifications @OhHiMark

Comment: Actually I have dig a bit more and found that nodes are being removed starting from the highest IDs. So in your case it would be Node-2, the one you wanted to delete.